# Returning text within a string in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, string, oracle

I have string data in a column of a table that will contain a monetary amount in it somewhere.

E.G. the column may contain something like:
"Dave once paid £50.00 to a lottery syndicate"
"Total Investment Returns for the fund in 2017 came to £150,964.39"

How can I search for the occurrence of the '£' sign and then return the number that occurs after it?

Thanks

Comment: Do you know beforehand that each row has at most one occurrence of the pound sign? What is the desired result if there is no pound sign at all - nothing included in the output, or include a NULL? What is the desired result if there is more than one pound sign? And, what if the text is like this: " The currency symbol for the pound is the £ character. "

Comment: There are a lot of such regex questions. Really, it is not a rocket science to write a regex like `£([0-9][0-9.,]*)`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, @MarcusESP79.  There are many ways to search for strings characters in SQL.  Please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  Probably some easy searches for previous questions and answers will increase your understanding of the topic.  Armed with that information, you may want to edit your question to include what you have attempted and how it is failing to meet your desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way. The search expression is a bit complicated because it must allow for thousand separators and decimal points, all optional. It assumes "Western" usage of thousands separators - it would have to be modified slightly to allow for Lakh (Indian) notation, for example. It will produce NULL when there is no pound sign, or if there is a pound sign not immediately followed by at least one digit. (So it will have to be modified slightly if you allow things like `£.60` instead of `£0.60`.) You can also capture just the amount (without the currency symbol) if desired - that is also a slight modification to the use of `REGEXP_SUBSTR` (use capture groups).

The biggest change would be needed if you may have more than one amount per input row.

```
with
     inputs ( str ) as (
       select 'Dave once paid £50.00 to a lottery syndicate.' from dual union all
       select 'Total Returns in 2017 came to £150,964.39.'    from dual
     )
-- End of simulated inputs (for testing purposes only, not part of the solution).
-- Use your actual table and column names in the SQL query below.
select str, regexp_substr(str, '£\d{1,3}(,?\d{3})*(\.\d+)?') as amount
from   inputs
;

STR                                            AMOUNT
---------------------------------------------  -----------
Dave once paid £50.00 to a lottery syndicate.  £50.00
Total Returns in 2017 came to £150,964.39.     £150,964.39
```

**Edit**

In a Comment below, the OP asked how to obtain just the amount, without the currency symbol. The easiest way is to use capture groups directly in the REGEXP_SUBSTR() function. The version below uses all six arguments to the function: as before the first is the input string and the second is the search pattern. The third and forth are the starting position and the occurrence (both always equal to 1 for this problem). The fifth, NULL, is for some special options we don't need. The sixth argument is relevant: 1 means return the first capture group, i.e. the part of the search pattern included in the first pair of matching parentheses (counting from left to right). Notice the additional pair of parentheses in the search pattern, to isolate the amount from the pound symbol:

```
regexp_substr(str, '£(\d{1,3}(,?\d{3})*(\.\d+)?)', 1, 1, null, 1)
```

**Edit #2**

To extract the amount in `NUMBER` data type, it is not necessary to remove the pound sign; the `TO_NUMBER()` function can handle it. Instead, the substring that is just the pound sign followed by the amount must be wrapped within `TO_NUMBER()`, using the proper format model and explicit currency symbol:

```
to_number(regexp_substr(str, '£\d{1,3}(,?\d{3})*(\.\d+)?'), 
               'L999,999,999,999,999.000000', 'nls_currency=£')
```

Just make sure to include enough digits on the right of the decimal point to accommodate all possible amounts. (Too many digits in the format model is never a problem.)

Comment: This is great and exactly what I'm after - thank you!!

The data is a lot more specific than my example but I can't extract as it is business info.

I'll try and be a bit more concise with my future questions, but this forum is new to me, as is Oracle SQL.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: @MarcusESP79 - OK, try to adapt to your actual data. If you run into difficulties, don't hesitate to come back here. Specific questions are the best: "I have this string, ...., and I need to extract .... so the desired result is .....  I tried this query:... which works in most cases, but in this example the difficulty is ....." A question asked this way may get a few upvotes right off the bat, just for being properly asked (which most questions on SO, unfortunately, are not...)

Comment: Thanks.
The difficulty here though is actually knowing where to start.  Despite many searches I had no idea what regexp_substr was....
So, how easy is it to change the selection to actually exclude the £ sign?
I could do it the only way I know which would be to manipulate some len() functions, but there must be a more elegant method?

Comment: @MarcusESP79 - It would be easier to use a TRIM() function (than using LENGTH()) but you don't need to do that. I will add to the answer to show how to use capture groups to get it all done in one pass. Just added to the Answer above.

Comment: @MarcusESP79 Or...wait - do you need to get a NUMBER from it (in NUMBER data type)? That can be done as well.

Comment: I've tried this and it works absolutely fine except where a line has a number bigger than 1,000

Without giving actual data, this is what the rows of data look like:

Some Text at 60 of £135.37 pa anonymous data 24/03/2011. No increases

Some Text at 60 of £1153.09 pa anonymous data 24/03/2011. No increases

Some Text at 60 of £293.76 pa anonymous data 24/03/2011. No increases

Comment: So what happens is that the 1st line is showing correctly as 135.37, but the 2nd line shows as 115, and the 3rd shows correctly as 293.76.
Any ideas?  I'm really struggling to get a grip on what the syntax is actually doing.